# How to make single query for UPDATE with different WHERE?

Tags: mysql

i want make single query with this statement, but I don't know how

```
UPDATE alarm SET alarm1 = 1 , alarm1time = NOW() WHERE alarm1 != 1 AND id = 1;
UPDATE alarm SET alarm2 = 1 , alarm2time = NOW() WHERE alarm2 != 1 AND id = 1;
UPDATE alarm SET alarm3 = 1 , alarm3time = NOW() WHERE alarm3 != 1 AND id = 1;
UPDATE alarm SET alarm4 = 1 , alarm4time = NOW() WHERE alarm4 != 1 AND id = 1;
``
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE alarm
SET
    alarm1 = CASE WHEN alarm1 <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE alarm1 END,
    alarm1time = CASE WHEN alarm1 <> 1 THEN NOW() ELSE alarm1time END,
    alarm2 = CASE WHEN alarm2 <> 1 AND THEN 1 ELSE alarm2 END,
    alarm2time = CASE WHEN alarm2 <> 1 THEN NOW() ELSE alarm2time END,
    alarm3 = CASE WHEN alarm3 <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE alarm3 END,
    alarm3time = CASE WHEN alarm3 <> 1 THEN NOW() ELSE alarm3time END,
    alarm4 = CASE WHEN alarm4 <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE alarm4 END,
    alarm4time = CASE WHEN alarm4 <> 1 THEN NOW() ELSE alarm4time END
WHERE id = 1;
```

This gets the job done with a single update statement.  That being said, I don't like what I wrote, and I actually prefer your version of using several different update statements, because it is clean and easier to read.  If you want to run the 4 updates atomically, then do so from a single explicit transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE id = 1 AND ( alarm1 != 1 OR alarm2 != 1 OR ... )
```

Should be fine, but every database use different syntax, so `( )` may be a problem there.